# Calculate $\int_{C}\frac{e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}}{1-z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Calculate $$\int_{C}\frac{e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}}{1-z^2}$$
>
> Where $C=\{|z|=2\}$

Ok so if I write $f(z)=\frac{e^{z+\frac{1}{z}}}{1-z^2}=\frac{e^z}{1-z^2}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{z}}$

Then $f(z)$ has an esential singularity in $0$. I know that $Res(e^{\frac{1}{z}},0)=e^0 = 1$ But I don't know how to calculate the residue of my $f$. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Try to find the residue of $f$  at $z=\infty$.

Then , given integral $=-2\pi i.Res(f,\infty)$. Since , $Res(f,0)+Res(f,1)+Res(f,-1)=-Res(f,\infty)$